SOAP service testing in C# empty date yielding error
So I am writing tests for a legacy web service. I have a Visual Studio (c#) project. I have added the correct service reference. There is a method for adding a contact. When I do so, everything works magnificently until I do a test with a piece of data that causes the response to have more data.
Example one: Give the request the basic data. Response comes back and is deserialized. All is well.
Example two: Add another element to the request. This element causes the response to include a segment that is not included in example one. In this segment is a date. The generated code for de/serializing is:
    /// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="date", Order=3)]
public System.DateTime ExpirationDate {
    get {
        return this.expirationDateField;
    }
    set {
        this.expirationDateField = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged("ExpirationDate");
    }
}

I take a look at the response in fiddler, and I see:

The tag is present. There is no value.
How do I handle an empty element which is supposed to desserialize to a date?
I see the definition documented for consumers

I would expect (I think?) that this field should be indicated with a "?" ([date?]). Correct?
In any event. I am not the creator or developer of this service, just the tester.
Is it possible to handle this such that it can successfully desserialize, perhaps to a default date like 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM perhaps?
Thanks

can you please show the corresponding part of the wsdl of the service?








Hmmmmm, does this behavior represent an error in the response? (Yay, I can punt this back to dev, tee hee).  Expiration has a default. Should the response not contain a default given this wsdl? Thanks

I'm not quit sure, but from the WSDL it looks like the response is incorrect (has incorrect format). WSDL says that ExpirationDate is required and can't be empty. But service responded with empty value.
